# Пунктуация в предложении "Постоим немного(,) и можно идти"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Ставится ли запятая в данном предложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ второй (без вопросительной интонации)

Правильно: ***Постоим немного, и можно идти.***

Запятая ставится в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП), состоящем из двух простых предложений.

**Первое предложение** односоставное определенно-личное,  предикативной основой является глагол «постоим».

**Второе предложение** односоставное безличное,  «можно идти»  – составное глагольное сказуемое, вспомогательная часть выражена предикативным модальным наречием «можно».

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится:

*Постоим немного, **и можно идти**?*

1. Вопросительным является только второе предложение, поэтому здесь нет общей вопросительной интонации. Соответственно, правило Розенталя здесь не применяется.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Пункт 3. Запятая перед соединительным и разделительным союзами в сложносочиненном предложении не ставится, если в его состав в качестве частей входят:

1. вопросительные предложения: Это кто такие и что им надобно? (П.) — объединяет вопросительная интонация; Который теперь час и сколько времени осталось до отхода поезда?;

2. Но вопросительный знак в конце ставится.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

Пункт 3. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложносочиненного предложения, если все части, входящие в его состав (**или только последняя**), заключают в себе вопрос: В ней сердце долго ли страдало, иль скоро слёз прошла пора? (П.) Жить с ними надоест, и в ком не сыщешь пятен? (Гр.)

Comment: Sharon, автор вопроса не предполагал никаких вопросительных интонаций в этом предложении (см. название). Знак вопроса у него относится к "внешнему" предложению ("ставится ли...?").

Comment: Спасибо за замечание.  Мне показался несложным вопрос,  вот я и "решила", что само предложение вопросительное.  Извините за невнимательность.